# Load and perform search on large amount of data

Tags: iphone, data-structures

I need a suggest how to operate with large amount of data on iPhone. Let say I have xml file with ~120k text records. I need to perform search on this data. The solution i have tried is to use Core Data to store information in sorted order in caches. And then use binary search which works fast. But the problem is to build  this caches. On first launch application takes about 15-25 seconds to build this caches. Maybe I need to use different approach to search the data?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an XML file with the requirement that you can't cache, then you're not going to succeed unless you somehow carefully format your XML file to have useful data traversal properties -- but then you may as well use a binary file that's more useful unless you have some very esoteric requirements.

Really what you want is one of the typical indexing algorithms (on disk hash, B-tree, etc) from the get-go.

**However**...

If you *have* to read in and parse your XML text file, then you can skirt using a typical big and slow generic XML parser and write a fast hackish version since most of the data records you'll need to recognize are probably formatted the same way over and over. Nothing special, just find where the relevant data fields start, grab the data until it ends, move on to the next data field.

Honestly, 120k of text isn't very much-- sounds like whatever XML parser you're using is just slow. (I use this trick all the time for autogenerated XML data that just represents things like tables or simple data records -- my own parser is faster than any generic XML parser.)

This is probably the solution you actually want since you sound fairly attached to the XML file format. It won't be as error-proof as a generic XML parser if you're not careful, however it will eat that 120KB file up like nobody's business. And it's entry level CS work -- read in a file with certain specific formatting and grab the data values from it. Regexps are your friend if you have access to them.

Answer (score 0):

Try storing and doing your searches in the cloud. (using a database stored on a server somewhere)

Unless you specifically need ALL of the information on the device..